# .NET Garbage Collector - what is its thread priority?

Tags: .net, garbage-collection

I have found some great articles ([Maoni](http://blogs.msdn.com/maoni/default.aspx), [Richter #1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/bb985010.aspx), [Richter #2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/bb985011.aspx)) giving many details as to the theory and practice of the GC, yet I cannot find anything that states how the GC's thread priority is set.

The closest I've found is this one that states that the Finalizer thread ["runs asynchronously to the application and at a high priority."](http://blogs.msdn.com/cbrumme/archive/2003/04/15/51319.aspx)

I always thought that it was a "low-priority" thread, but reading more and more about it that seems to be wrong (since the GC has to block all your other threads, and you don't want to have your app depend on a low-priority thread in order to resume in a timely fashion).

Does anybody know for sure know what the actual priority is supposed to be?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In *CLR via C#*, Richter explains that:

> A special high-priority CLR thread is dedicated to calling `Finalize` methods

(see the "Finalization Internals" heading of chapter 20)

This is the only context in which he talks about a garbage collector thread. A little earlier in the chapter, he explains that garbage collection is started in response to one of the following events:

- Generation 0 is full
- Call to `GC.Collect`
- Windows is reporting low memory conditions
- The CLR is unloading an AppDomain
- The CLR is shutting down

...which suggests that the only thread created by the garbage collector is this single, "high-priority" finalizer thread.

**Edit:** He then goes on, in "Concurrent Collection", to explain that:

> On a multiprocessor system running the workstation version of the execution engine, the garbage collector has an additional background thread to collect objects concurrently while the application runs. [...] **The garbage collector has a normal priority background thread that marks unreachable objects.**

Comment: This seems as close to a full answer as I might get.  I'll leave it open a bit longer, but I think this might do it. Thanks!  Learn something new everyday, huh?  Maybe I should buy his book.

Comment: I can definitely recommend his book -- it's interesting background information, and it's saved me on a few specific problems.

Comment: I think this is one of those rare instances where I could not find the answer online, but a book seems to have the answer in full detail. Thanks!

Comment: Does that mean that the Finalizer thread spawns a new thread for each Finalize method he calls, or does he run the Finalize methods himself? Or perhaps he uses a pool of threads (ThreadPool?).

Comment: The finalizer thread maintains a single queue of objects that need finalization, and runs finalizers in sequence.

Answer (score 6):

The GC thread runs at a normal priority.  The finalizer thread runs at "Highest" priority.

You can see this by turning on the Debug "Thread" window, and breaking anywhere in a managed application.  The threads are all listed (although they're not named), with their priorities.  It takes a bit to decipher which is which, but there will be an extra "Normal" and "Highest" priority thread, which correspond to the GC and the Finalizer thread.

Comment: That seems to make sense (normal for GC, highest for finalizer so as to get back without being pre-empted). I just wonder why that is not explictly explained anywhere on MSDN.  Have you been able to find anything more "formal" than just firing up the Thread window?

Comment: I don't know of anything specific.  I learned about some of this a while back at a conference talk by Rico Mariani talking about perf. in .NET - However, most of the MSDN docs basically say to ignore the GC internals and just trust them - and also don't rely on them staying the same, because they're free to change at any point (and have in the past).

Answer (score 1):

The thread that the GC runs on depends on which version of the GC your app is using.

The answer to this question is contained in a blog post I've written: **[How to determine which garbage collector is running](http://dave-black.blogspot.com/2012/04/how-to-determine-which-garbage.html)**

Answer (score 0):

the garbage collector runs at lower priority than critical threads

Answer (score 0):

The GC thread priority is an implementation detail, right now they are running in normal priority, however the finalizer thread is running as a high priority and has a timeout as well.